# How to recognize .pc extension

Tags: visual-studio-2008, oracle-pro-c

How to set so that all .pc file will be open with visual studio? and it also recognize it as C/C++ code as well. I did the setting in registry before. Unfortunately, I deleted the files and totally forgot how to it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go in windows Explorer to a .pc file and right-click and "open with" then choose Visual Studio and check the box to make this "default".

**EDIT :** Then you go in Visual Studio to Tools menu -> Options menu, -> Text Editor, File extenstion and assign .pc to C++ .

Comment: tried that.unfortunately it wont recognize the code in the .pc file as C/C++ codes,so it will be all black.